# Java frontend beginner

Tags: java, frontend

I have to build a simple java application so i am using Spring boot and hibernate as my frameworks . Its the first time i am doing this so i need all the help i can get, i manage to make the back end to work ,at least the most of it, but i was wondering what would be the easiest way to create a front end for my application ,something pretty basic , thank you in advance!

here is my main model

```
... 
package com.scheduler.backend.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person extends AbstractEntity {

    /**
     * 
     */
    //private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Column
    private String firstName;
    @Column
    private String lastName;
    @Column
    private PersonType type;
    @Column
    private Long calendarId;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public PersonType getType() {
        return type;
    }
    public void setType(PersonType type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
    public Long getCalendarId() {
        return calendarId;
    }
    public void setCalendarId(Long calendarId) {
        this.calendarId = calendarId;
    }
}
...
```

Comment: the model might not be usefull for my question but i had to put some code in order to post the question

Comment: Well this isn't the right place to ask this question..But There are plenty of option for developing front end. You can use anything like angular,react etc

Comment: Your question probably will be closed. Many people come here to downvote and flag to close the question but they won't answer. Maybe I'm wrong but it happened to me. Since you are a new member, don't afraid of these things. it is usual for newbies who don't know the rule, Try to do your best...cheers!!

Comment: This kind of question is off-topic here, and might be better asked on the sister site, [*Software Recommendations Stack Exchange*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Indeed, this is likely already to have been asked there. So search before posting. And if you do post, you will need to get much more specific about the criteria by which you would judge a solution as meeting your needs. As a Java programmer, I suggest looking at Vaadin, covered on that sister site several times.

Answer (score 1):

Two types of application can be built out of it. One is desktop app and another is we application.

If you are interested to develop a desktop application with java, hibernate, spring boot as framework, you have to use **Angular 7 with Electron** or **React with Electron**. You can refer below the following links for this.

https://electronjs.org/

https://github.com/cuba-labs/java-electron-tutorial

If you are interested to develop a web application, you can use Angular 7, React JS, Vue and many more Javascript framework with Java as backend. Although JSP, Java Server Faces are available, these technologies have become old. You can also use Apache wicket freemarker, Vaadin framework for UI rendering with Java. You can see below links.

https://vaadin.com/spring

https://wicket.apache.org/

https://freemarker.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your frontend using [JSP](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/index.htm) and [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)
or
Use some frameworks to easier your works ([Angular](https://angular.io/), [React](https://reactjs.org/)...)

See this for getting easier frontend by others opinion: [Simple frontend framework for backend guy](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/7e91l2/simple_frontend_framework_for_backend_guy/)

Answer (score 0):

*you can always consider the **Angularjs** as your frontend part. For that, you have to go through the basics of it.*

*here I refer the best what I found:*
https://angular.io/tutorial

*Just go through it, If you have basic knowledge of java you can easily comfortable in it.*